# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Mismatch between generated SQL and querybuilder results when selecting all models where two relationships are both absent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

Let's say I have a model `Foobar` with relationships named `baz` and `quux`. `Foobar` belongsTo `Baz` and `Baz` hasOne `Foobar`. This means there is a foreign key column in the `Foobar` table for `baz_id`. The relationships are defined correctly in the models. In case it is relevant, this model caching library is used on both models: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching

I would like to query all `Foobar` that do not have either relationship; meaning I only want to select `Foobar` where BOTH `baz` and `quux` relationships are absent. I do so as follows:

```
Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->get();
```

Now let's say `$foobar` is a `Foobar` instance with no relationships, and `$baz` is a freshly created `Baz` instance. I associate the two like so:

```
$baz->foobar()->associate($foobar);
$baz->save();
```

Now, I run the above query again. T**he row represented by `$foobar` is still appearing in the results, even though it shouldn't since it now has a non-null `baz` relationship.** My question is: why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I played around in artisan console while debugging this. In the same artisan session:

```
Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->get();
// This gets a collection that is not empty, the first item is a Foobar instance that definitely has a baz

Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->first();
// This is null (?)

Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->count();
// This is 0 (?)

Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->get()->get(0)->baz;
// This gets the Baz object attached to the first instance
```

To double-check that the SQL is correct:

```
Foobar::doesntHave('baz', 'AND')->doesntHave('quux')->get()->toSql();
// This outputs the generated raw SQL.
```

I input the raw SQL into a SQL client and got the correct result.

I also attempted / checked while debugging:

1. `$foobar->touch()` - did not change results.
2. Made sure API endpoint was not cached by browser, Cloudflare, or anything else

Comment: Instead of using `->get()` why don't you try `->toSql()` and see what query the builder is creating?

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks, I tried it and reveals the query is correct (in attempt 2 and 3), so that is even weirder. I get different (correct) result running the generated SQL in my SQL client. Which is even more puzzling.

Comment: So your problem is elsewhere then right? You should either add more of your code and update your question or close this question and create a new one.

Comment: Yep, I'm working on it

Comment: @bassxzero I've edited the question with details about the context of this code. I am not yet sure that the problem is elsewhere (I explain in my edit)

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are using the correct database connection? Can you try a more simple query to make sure it's querying the correct database?

Comment: Yes @bassxzero it's the correct DB connection. BTW I messed up when I was testing in artisan, I edited my question to be accurate now. I can reproduce the issue in artisan console, so it is a problem with the query, not the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue originated in the model caching library used on these models: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching

When I ran the library's command for completely invalidating `Foobar` cache, it resolved the issue. It looks like the library does not correctly invalidate cache in this scenario, though I can't explain why without digging deeper into the library. Their README indicates this may be a known issue.

```
php artisan modelCache:clear --model='App\Models\Foobar'
```

To work around it, a few options came to mind:

1. Programmatically run the artisan command for clearing model cache whenever the relationship is updated.
2. Rewrite query to bypass model caching.
3. Look for different model caching library.

We opted to remove model caching from these models entirely; we were able to do so because it was an "easy" premature optimization, but may not be necessary. We reasoned that we will remove the premature optimization for now and worry about it again only if it causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```php
Foobar::whereDoesntHave('baz')->whereDoesntHave('guux')->get();
```

Comment: This gives the same incorrect result. But see comments on question; I think my code might be correct and something weirder is going on